# Splitting non-equally file in bash

Tags: bash, split

I have a file in csv format. I know positions where I want to chip off a chunk from the file and write it as a new csv file.

*split* command splits a file into equal-sized chunks. I wonder if there exists an effective (the file is huge) way to split file into chunks of different sizes?

Comment: You might want to look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to split the file at a newline character. If this is the case you can use the [`head`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head) and [`tail`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) commands to grab a number of lines from the beginning and from the end of your file, respectively.

If you want to copy a new of lines from within the file you can use [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), e.g.

```
sed -e 1,Nd -e Mq file
```

where N should be replaced with the line number of the line preceding the first line to display and M should be the line number of the last line to display.

Comment: So, last command is helpful. But how do I write these lines to a new file?

Comment: Just [redirect](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) it to a file which doesn't exist in the current directory, e.g. `sed -e 1,10d -e 20q big.csv > small.csv`